# Memory error in pycharm using scipy's welch function

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, pycharm

I want to get the Welch's periodogram using scipy.signal in pycharm. My signal is an 5-min audio file with Fs = 48 kHz, so I guess it's a very big signal. The line was:

```
f, p = signal.welch(audio, Fs, nperseg=512)
```

I am getting a memory error. I was wondering if that's a pycharm configuration thing, or it's just a too big signal. My RAM is 8 Gb.

Sometimes it works with some audio files, but the idea is to do it with several, so after one or two, the error raises.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your setup and `welch` does not seem to be the problem. For further analysis the entire script you are running would be necessary.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import welch

fs = 48000
signal_length = 5 * 60 * fs

audio_signal = np.random.rand(signal_length)
f, Pxx = welch(audio_signal, fs=fs, nperseg=512)
```

On my computer (windows 10, 64 bit) it consumes 600 MB of peak memory during the call to `welch` which gets recycled directly afterwards, additionally to ~600MB of allocation for the initial array and Python itself. The call to `welch` itself does not lead to any permanent significant memory increase.

You can do the following:

- Upgrade to newest version of `scipy`, as there have been [problems](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/6993) with Welch previously
- Check that your PC has enough free memory and close memory-hungry applications (eg. chrome)
- Convert your array in a lower datatype e.g. from `float64` to `float32` or `float16`
- Make sure to free variables that are not needed anymore . Especially if you load several signals and store the result in different arrays, it can accumulate quite quickly. Only keep what you need and delete vars via `del variable_name`, check that there are no references remaining elsewhere in the program. E.g if you don't need the `audio` variable, either delete it explicitly after `welch(...)` or overwrite it with the next audio data.
- Run the [garbage collector](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html) `gc.collect()`. However, this will probably not solve your problem as garbage is managed automatically in Python anyway.